# webpage opened by selenium closed unexpectedly

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter

I am a bit new to **tkinter** and
I tried to use **selenium** and **tkinter** for building an interface
but opened webpage in chrome closed unexpectedly, any ideas ?

```python
import tkinter as tk
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()

def hello (): 
   driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
   driver.get("https://google.com") 
   search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']")
   search.send_keys('hello')
   search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
button1 = tk.Button(text='Click Me',command=hello, bg='brown',fg='white')
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=button1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you see any error?

Comment: no it just disappears after running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to `@undetected Selenium`
but with little change:

```
def hello (): 
   global driver
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe')
   driver.get("https://google.com") 
   search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']")
   search.send_keys('hello')
   search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

you have to pass **driver** as a **global variable** and then send both the key and the value as :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe')
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the value of the key *`executable_path`* you may like to send both the *key* and the *value* as follows:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe')
```